# Understanding JavaBeans pattern (Abstract getter and setter)

Tags: java, class, interface, javabeans

I'm working on a web-application now and have the following class hiereachy:

```
public class AbstractCreator{

    public Object create(){
        getCreateService().crete();
    }

    public abstract CreateService getCreateService();

    public abstract void setCreateService(CreateService createService);

}
```

Descendants:

```
public class SubCreator extends Creator{

    @Named("subCreateService") //I prefer using that annotation
                                    // instead of the legacy @Autowired
    private CreateService createService;

    @Override
    public CreateService getCreateService() {
        return createService;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreateService(CreateService createService) {
        this.createService = createService;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MegaSubCreator extends Creator{

    @Named("megaSubCreateService") 
    private CreateService createService;

    @Override
    public CreateService getCreateService() {
        return createService;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreateService(CreateService createService) {
        this.createService = createService;
}
```

where `CreateService` is just an interface:

```
public interface CreateService{
    public Object create();
}
```

***The problem***: I need to use the service in the `abstract class` but the information about the service is available only from concrete subclasses where we perform injection. Is it correct to use abstract getter/setter in such circumstances?

I mean, doesn't it contradict to the `JavaBeans` pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really bother about the `JavaBeans` pattern - just renaming the methods will do.

That said, I think the model itself doesn't seem right to me. An `AbstractCreator` requires `CreatorService` and as such the `CreatorService` should be part of the `AbstractCreator`. `AbstractCreator` can have a constructor that takes `CreatorService` as a parameter and use constructor injection in the subclasses to set it.

Comment: Indeed, the idea about the constructor sounds good. Thank you.